# How can I restrict API endpoints to only manipulate data that the user owns?

Tags: .net, rest, asp.net-core

I have ASP.NET Core web API with following controllers:

- book
- picture
- video

so now user can call the API for example to get all:

- GET service.local/_api/book
- GET service.local/_api/video

Now I would like to implement routing to manipulate (get, post, put) entires only assigned to currently logged user, for example:

- GET service.local/_api/my/book - will return all books assigned to current user
- PUT service.local/api/my/book/12 - update book assigned to current user

How I can do this? I will add more controllers in the feature. for now I have one default routing implemented.

Comment: Are you asking for [Resource-base Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example (Routes witch include 'my' will extract the user):

```
[Authorize]
[Route("_api")]
public class BookController : Controller
{
    private UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public BookController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    [HttpGet("[controller]")]
    public IActionResult Book()
    {
        return Content("All books");
    }

    [HttpGet("my/[controller]")]
    public IActionResult RootBook()
    {
        var user = _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
        return Content("All root user Books");
    }

    [HttpPut("[controller]/{id}")]
    public IActionResult Book(int id)
    {
        return Content($"Update Book {id}");
    }

    [HttpPut("my/[controller]/{id}")]
    public IActionResult RootBook(int id)
    {
        var user = _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
        return Content($"Update root user Book {id}");
    }
}
```

Test samples.

General Book:

[image: General]

Root user book:

[image: Root]

Comment: thx. I thought It would by more complicated but indeed it is as simple.

Answer (score 0):

Your "my" routes simply need to implicitly filter by the authorized user's id. Obviously, this assumes you've already implemented auth in your project and are sending requests to these "my" routes with an appropriate `Authorization` header so the the user principal will be populated.

You can get the authorized user's id in your controller via: `User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)`. Then, once you have that, you simply limit your queries with that. For example:

```
var books = _context.Books.Where(x => x.OwnerId == userId);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add "id" to route

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserBookAsync(string id) { 
// code here
 }
```

Comment: Why? The user id can be read from the current identity claim. And what is Id? The id of the book or the id of the user?

Comment: It's id of book